# Not able to calling NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable

Tags: python, iphone, ios, objective-c, sockets

I've written a server with Python (Twisted). I have connected to server and sending data to server but I'm not getting any data from server and NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable not getting called.

This is how I connect to the server:

```
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"localhost", 3000, &readStream, &writeStream);
inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
[inputStream setDelegate:self];
[outputStream setDelegate:self];
[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[inputStream open];
[outputStream open];
```

here is the problem:

```
-(void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent
{
     NSString *event;
     switch (streamEvent)
     {
         case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
         event = @"NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable";
         if (theStream == inputStream)
         {
             uint8_t buffer[1024];
             int len;
             while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable])
             {
                NSLog(@"input =====%@",inputStream);

                len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:1024];
                NSLog(@"len -=======%d",len);
                if (len > 0)
                {
                    NSMutableString *output = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                    NSLog(@"Received data--------------------%@", output);
                }
             }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

This is the server side code:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol
from twisted.internet import reactor

class IphoneChat(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.clients.append(self)
        print "clients are ", self.factory.clients

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        a = data.split(':')
        print a
        if len(a) > 1:
           command = a[0]
           content = a[1]

           msg = ""
           if command == "msg":
               msg = content
               print msg

    def message(self, message):
        self.transport.write(message + '\n')

        for c in self.factory.clients:
            c.message(msg)

factory = Factory()
factory.protocol = IphoneChat
factory.clients = []
reactor.listenTCP(650, factory)
print "Iphone Chat server started"
reactor.run()
```

I have tried a lot and googled,but I did not find any solution. It's killing my time so if any one have worked on it please guide me and post sample code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does `message` method get invoked? That's not something `twisted` would call right? I'd say you might need a call to `message` function within `dataReceived`.

Comment: please change my code

Comment: try doing a `self.message(msg)` after `print msg` within your `if` block.

Comment: Please checkout my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about iphone, but I find some things wrong with your server. I'd rather write it as

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol
from twisted.internet import reactor

class IphoneChat(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.clients.append(self)
        print "clients are ", self.factory.clients

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        a = data.split(':')
        print a
        if len(a) > 1:
           command = a[0]
           content = a[1]

           msg = ""
           if command == "msg":
               msg = content
               self.message(msg)
               print msg

    def message(self, message):
        for c in self.factory.clients:
            c.transport.write(message + '\n')

factory = Factory()
factory.protocol = IphoneChat
factory.clients = []
reactor.listenTCP(650, factory)
print "Iphone Chat server started"
reactor.run()
```

When I tested it out with a telnet client, it worked out well.